# How to Check if a Div is Empty and Then Execute Action

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, contains

I'm Building a Personal Assistant with HTML5, CSS, & **Javascript**

This is what my *current* Problem is.

I Have a `<div>` that contains scripts with the responses for when a Question is asked and if the question matches one it writes that response.

I Need a Script that will check if this div is empty, in **Javascript**, not **jQuery**

I need to check if the div is empty because that means there is no response.

Then for it to redirect to an the error page.

a Question & the response to it would look like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
{
var q = getValue("q");
var name = getValue("name");
}
if (q == 'Whats+up') {
document.write("Not much " + name + ".");
}
else {

}
</script>
```

This is the last code I tried:

```
            <script>

    var theDiv = document.getElementById("responce");
    var q = getValue("q");
    if(theDiv.innerHTML == ''){
    window.location = 'error.html?name=Brandon&q='+q;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Just to be sure : the div is filled by your own server ? [If not, you can't look at what is inside the div](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: "I Have a <div> that contains scripts..." If this is true, `innerHTML`of the `DIV` is never `''`, though you can't see anything in the browser, the script is a part of the HTML of the `DIV`.

Comment: if no one knows how to fix this is there _another way_ this could work?

Comment: I tried having one of the question & response scripts `document.write("error")` and have a script check if that's the only word in the div but it never worked out, any thoughts?

Comment: Be careful with `document.write`. It's purposed to create the whole new document rather than append text in the present document, i.e. if it is used from a function after the page has been parsed, it automatically calls `document.open()`, which wipes out ALL earlier code in the document.

Comment: its done that on most of my documents but with this it just writes the specified code where I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
var q = getValue("q");
var name = getValue("name");
}
if (q == 'Whats+up') {
document.write("<div id='response_text'>"+"Not much " + name + "."+"</div>");
}
else {

}
</script>
```

And then:

```
<script>

var theDiv = document.getElementById("response_text");
var q = getValue("q");
if(theDiv==null || theDiv.innerHTML == ''){
window.location = 'error.html?name=Brandon&q='+q;
}
</script>
```

That being said, there are probably better/more scalable ways of doing this with ajax.

Comment: I tried that and the error script made it so every question went to the error page. I tried messing around with it to make it work, but thank you for the help!

Comment: if no one knows how to fix this is there another way this could work?

Comment: I'd have to see the code to try to fix it. is there anyway you can set up a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: **beware**, it must have a `?q=some%20query` to generate a responce

Comment: I tried having one of the question & response scripts `document.write("error")` and have a script check if that's the only word in the div but it never worked out, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could check, if there are no other elements than `script`s in the `div`:

```
<script>
    var theDiv = document.getElementById('responce'),
        q = getValue('q'),
        scripts = theDiv.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT').length;
    if (theDiv.children.length - scripts === 0) {
        window.location = 'error.html?name=Brandon&q=' + q;
    }
</script>
```

However, I'd suggested you to get rid of all inline scripts, and put them in the `head` of the document or just before the closing `body` tag instead.

**EDIT**

A quick-fix would be to move the `script` below the `#responce`.

Comment: I tried this and I'm not sure, your script says to have the scripts in the div, but you're saying to have them out. I tried this with the scripts in and out and both didn't work, but thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried having one of the question & response scripts `document.write("error")` and have a script check if that's the only word in the div but it never worked out, any thoughts?